# Windows 8 app settings best practice

Tags: javascript

When I am building an application in PHP with the Zend framework, there is an application.ini file with all the settings the application need even with environment inheritance.

Is there something similer on the Metro style Windows.JavaScript app?

I mean not a settings Flyout for the users but some internal settings.

I hope I made my self clear ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i would use ressources : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465248.aspx

but there 's no environment inheritence, as far as i know